# Why am I not able to update data in SQLite database from Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to update or rather modify the existing data in the particular cell of a SQLite database from Flask Python. But I can't update. Also I didn't receive any error while doing so. At the same time, I am able to insert a new data in the new row of the table.

Server side code:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/<state>")
def get_post_javascript_data(state=None):
        connection = sqlite3.connect('/home/pi/toggle7.db')
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        load = 'light5'
        status = 'ON'
        if state == 'Load1on':
                sock.send('Load1ON')
                print ("sent: Load1ON")
                try:
                     cursor.execute("UPDATE user1 SET load = 'light5' WHERE id='1'")
                     connection.commit()
                     message = "success"
                except:
                     connection.rollback()
                     message = "failure"
                finally:
                     connection.close()
                     print (message)
```

Comment: Can someone say why this question is down voted? This blocks me asking further question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE user1 SET load = 'light5' WHERE id='1'
```

This command updates all rows that have the value `'1'` in the `id` column.
If nothing happens, then this implies that there is no such row.

If the `id` column contains numbers, then you must search for a number:

```sql
... WHERE id=1
```

And you should always use parameters to avoid formatting problems like this (and SQL injection attacks):

```py
cursor.execute('UPDATE user1 SET load = ? WHERE id = ?', ['light5', 1])
```